# Can reduceBykey be used to change type and combine values - Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

In code below I'm attempting to combine values:

```
val rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String), Double)] =
    sc.parallelize(List(
      (("a"), 1.0),
      (("a"), 3.0),
      (("a"), 2.0)
      ))

val reduceByKey = rdd.reduceByKey((a , b) => String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b))
```

`reduceByValue` should contain (a , 1,3,2) but receive compile time error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - type mismatch; found : String required: Double - type mismatch; found : String 
 required: Double
```

What determines the type of the reduce function? Can the type not be converted?

I could use `groupByKey` to achieve same result but just want to understand `reduceByKey`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, given an rdd of type `RDD[(K,V)]`, `reduceByKey` will take an associative function of type `(V,V) => V`.

If we want to apply a reduction that changes the type of the values to another arbitrary type, then we can use `aggregateByKey`:

```
def aggregateByKey[U](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)
```

Using the `zeroValue` and the `seqOp` function, it provides a fold-like operation at the map side while the associate function `combOp` combines the results of the `seqOp` to the final result, much like reduceByKey would do. 
As we can appreciate from the signature, while the collection values are of type `V` the result of `aggregateByKey` will be of an arbitrary type `U`

Applied to the example above,  `aggregateByKey` would look like this:

```
rdd.aggregateByKey("")({case (aggr , value) => aggr + String.valueOf(value)}, (aggr1, aggr2) => aggr1 + aggr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that your Value type mismatch. You can achieve the same output with reduceByKey, provided you changed the type of value in your RDD.

```
val rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String), String)] =
    sc.parallelize(List(
      ("a", "1.0"),
      ("a", "3.0"),
      ("a", "2.0")
      ))

    val reduceByKey = rdd.reduceByKey((a , b) => a.concat(b))
```

Here is the same example. As long as the function you pass to reduceByKey takes two parameter of the type Value( Double in your case ) and returns a single parameter of the same type, your reduceByKey will work.