# Spark/Scala : Creating Nested Structure using ReduceByKey using RDD only

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Spark/Scala : Creating Nested Structure using ReduceByKey using RDD only

I want to create nested Structure only using RDD. I am able to do this using groupBy function, which is not performing well for huge data. So I want to do it using reduceByKey, but I am not able to get what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

**Input Data:**

```
val sales=sc.parallelize(List(
  ("West",  "Apple",  2.0, 10),
  ("West",  "Apple",  3.0, 15),
  ("West",  "Orange", 5.0, 15),
  ("South", "Orange", 3.0, 9),
  ("South", "Orange", 6.0, 18),
  ("East",  "Milk",   5.0, 5)))
```

**Required Output** is List of Structs. I am able to do this using `groupByKey` Like below:

```
sales.map(value => (value._1 ,(value._2,value._3,value._4  )) )
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .map { case(k,v) => (k, v.map(_._2)) }
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)

// (South,List((Orange,3.0,9), (Orange,6.0,18)))
// (East,List((Milk,5.0,5)))
// (West,List((Apple,2.0,10), (Apple,3.0,15), (Orange,5.0,15)))
```

But I want to achieve the same thing using `reduceByKey`. I am not able to get List[Struct]. Instead I can get List[List]. Is there any way to get List[Struct]?

```
sales.map(value => (value._1 ,List(value._2,value._3,value._4)))
  .reduceByKey((a,b) => (a ++ b))
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)

// (South,List(Orange, 3.0, 9, Orange, 6.0, 18))
// (East,List(Milk, 5.0, 5))
// (West,List(Apple, 2.0, 10, Apple, 3.0, 15, Orange, 5.0, 15))

sales.map(value => (value._1 ,List(value._2,value._3,value._4)))
  .reduceByKey((a,b) =>(List(a) ++ List(b)))
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)

// (South,List(List(Orange, 3.0, 9), List(Orange, 6.0, 18)))
// (East,List(Milk, 5.0, 5))
// (West,List(List(List(Apple, 2.0, 10), List(Apple, 3.0, 15)), List(Orange, 5.0, 15)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **You cannot** - `reduceByKey` requires a function `(V, V) ⇒ V` therefore it cannot change the types. See for example [Can reduceBykey be used to change type and combine values - Scala Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535060/8371915)
- You can use `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey` but **it won't improve performance** because your process doesn't reduce amount of data. See for example [Spark groupByKey alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31029395/8371915).
- You can gain **a little** with (no need for temporary objects):

  ```
  sales.map(value => (value._1 ,(value._2,value._3,value._4)) ).groupByKey
  ```